# Get the number of queries in a batch

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using batch execution with prepared statements to reduce the number of times I need to query the database.

The code that I am planning to write as part of our DB interface looks something like this

```
public void insertPerson(String name ) {
   psInsertPerson.setString(1, name);
   psInsertPerson.addBatch();
}
```

I can keep track of how many objects are in the batch by explicitly keeping track of it whenever the method is called, but is there a way to just ask the prepared statement how many it's batched up?

Comment: Looks like there isn't, so you have to do this manually.

Comment: I wonder if it would be feasible to write a wrapper around the prepared statement just so I don't have to keep track of it manually in any code that wants to be know it.

Comment: I guess you could, but IMO it would be easier just to maintain the counter in the class/method that uses the `PreparedStatement`.